# How to log in programmatically and then switch to WebDriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know that the "log in programmatically" question has been asked before, but here is what I am trying to do.

I have many python functional tests that login each time to the web app to execute each scenario. The log in has come to be the most tested feature and I would like to skip it. That means to avoid the UI to save time.
I am trying to login by sending a post request using the Requests python library and then switch , somehow , to webdriver and continue the test in the authorized part.

Here is what i have done so far (the code is from another SO post).

```
def login_robot(username,password):
    import requests
    # Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
    payload = {'username': username, 'password': password}
    login_url = "https://www.webapp.com/login/index.php"

    # Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.post(login_url, data=payload)

        # # An authorised request.
        r = s.get('http://www.webapp.com/wall.php')
        print r.text
```

The r.text prints the page behind the login correctly. 
How should I connect this with the webdriver launching an actual firefox instance? 
Are these two , two entirely different browser instances?

Comment: It'd only be fair (not to mention proper) to change ("the code is from another SO post") to a link so it's somewhat attributable :)

Comment: I would be more than happy to do that, (credits must be assigned) but I copy pasted the snippet during my research a while ago and I cannot trace it back.

Comment: `requests` and the browser launched by Selenium are two different entities. The key here would be to move the credentials that become associated with `requests` (post-login) to the browser launched by Selenium. If you use cookies for this, this means passing cookies. I don't know the details of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most "programmatic" method, but the most simple solution imo would be to make a rudimentary "login_form.html" that selenium can use to login

```
<form id="login" action="https://www.webapp.com/login/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="wehappyfew" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="qwerty1234" />
</form>
```

then just do:

```
driver.get( "file:///C:/location/of/login_form.html" )
driver.find_element_by_css_selector( "form#login" ).submit()
```